# How to change the values of a customer_profile address field in the validation function?

Tags: 7, forms

In my checkout form, I have 2 customer profiles: billing (default) and shipping (from commerce shipping module).

Basically, I need to emulate the commerce_shipping 7.x-1 option "copy shipping information from billing", but i need to do that manually in a validation function (the values depends from few factors).

My code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // [...cut...]
    array_unshift($form['buttons']['continue']['#validate'], '_MYMODULE_validate_checkout');
}

function _MYMODULE_validate_checkout($form, &$form_state)
{
    // a custom checkbox i added in MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter
    if($form_state['values']['b2s'] == 1)
    {
        form_set_value(
            $form['customer_profile_shipping']['customer_profile']['#value']->commerce_customer_address,
            $form['customer_profile_billing']['customer_profile']['#value']->commerce_customer_address['und'][0],
            $form_state
        );
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

Notice: Undefined index: #parents in form_set_value() (line 2514 di /httpdocs/includes/form.inc).

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be an array, null given, called in /httpdocs/includes/form.inc on line 2514 and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value() (linea 6440 di /httpdocs/includes/common.inc).

I also tryed:

```
$form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['customer_profile']->commerce_customer_address['und'][0] = $form_state['values']['customer_profile_billing']['customer_profile']->commerce_customer_address['und'][0];
```

and i dont get any errors, but it doesnt works.

Any idea?
Basically, for now i just need to copy billing address into shipping address when my `b2s` checkbox is checked (when i understand how to do that, i will add my custom logic)

Comment: Why not copy address from billing to shipping text box using jquery/js ?

Comment: @2-Stroker I already do that, but i have few logic that cant be implemented client side (and btw i dont like to rely only on javascript for a thing that is mandatory for my site)